# grep not matching - I can see the line in the file

Tags: grep

This is driving me nuts - I must be doing something wrong.

The line is :

```
<000143> 0000000000150622 R WM_KILLFOCUS
```

I'm grepping with

```
cat file | grep --ignore-case "FOCUS"
```

(I know, UUOC). And getting nothing, the line (and others containing "FOCUS") are definitely in the file.

I know I'm missing something stupid - but what is it?

Comment: I don't see any issue with that. If you do cat file | less and go down to that line, it looks exactly like what you posted?

Comment: Good catch - it doesn't at all. The file was generated in windows, I used a text editor to change the encoding.

Comment: Yeah. So you probably need to use some tool like iconv to change it over to UTF-8